# Error on Angular5 Importing RxJS in the project

Tags: typescript, rxjs, angular5

Observable not found, what do I? I do not know how to use rxjs on http. anyone can tell me Please?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { IEmployee } from './employee';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable ';

@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService {

  private _url: string = "/assests/data/employee.json";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getEmployees(): Observable<IEmployee[]>{ 
    return this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(this._url);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the space in the import for Observable a typo? If not try and remove it

Comment: After removing also not working?

Comment: Whats the rxjs version from your package.json file?

Comment: I was using 6 and working on 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of rxjs 6, you need to import Observable like this:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

You can check it here:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs#installation-and-usage

Comment: You can install `rxjs-compat` to keep the old api for a little while but it will go away with version 7.

Comment: And if you use `rxjs-compat` you can use `rxjs-tslint` which will give you lint errors if you are using deprecated features which will allow you to slowly migrate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping you're using old version of angular that's why you're facing this problem, try to update every package and go to the main official page of angluar to learn about!